# Default for a missing field when deserializing Json with Jerkson

Tags: json, scala, jackson

When parsing Json with the Jerkson library following the example in the docs:

```
case class Person(id: Long, name: String)
parse[Person]("""{"id":1,"name":"Coda"}""") //=> Person(1,"Coda")
```

If I try and deserialize Json that doesn't contain both the id and the name fields then an error is thrown saying they are needed. Is there a way of setting it up so that if the following Json for a Person was parsed:

```
{"id":2}
```

The name field could be defaulted to "John". (I thought this might be possible by setting a default in the parameter in the case class but no luck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [pull request](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson/pull/42) I did for the Jerkson library. It adds support for case class default parameters.

Pay heed to user ksvladimir's comment, though, which I haven't had time to add to the pull request. (I'll update this answer when I do)

Comment: Thank you, seems like you had the same thought I did :) . I'll keep an eye on the pull request. In the meantime, any suggestions for a strategy for dealing with times when a parameter might be optional?

Comment: Pleasure :) You could always bundle a custom Jerkson with your app until they merge. Check out my branch, apply ksvladimir's mods, ```sbt package```, copy the JAR to ```lib```, and make sure you remove the Jerkson dependency from build.sbt so the one in ```lib``` is used.

Comment: Sorry been on holiday so just seen this. Thanks will give that a go!

Comment: Managed to get some time to try this. Cloned your repo and then built (using maven as sbt was complaining about jackson dependencies...). Dropped the jar in lib and removed the jerkson dependency. Now it doesn't compile complaining that: 
"[error] class file needed by Parser is missing.
[error] reference value codehaus of package org refers to nonexisting symbol."
Any ideas? Sorry I'm struggling! It compiled using the jar from the codahale repo.